# How to specify depth in queries with Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, lazy-loading, spring-data-neo4j

I try to do a directory structure with Neo4j and Spring Data (spring-data-neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE).

I have a Directory bean :

```
@NodeEntity
public class Directory {
    @GraphId private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_CHILD_CONTENT", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Directory> subDirectories;

    public void hasChildContent(Directory subDir) {
        if (subDirectories == null) {
            subDirectories = new HashSet<>();
        }
    subDirectories.add(subDir);
}
```

and my Repository :

```
public interface DirectoryRepository extends GraphRepository<Directory> {
    @Query("MATCH (a:Directory) WHERE NOT ()-[:HAS_CHILD_CONTENT]->(a) RETURN a ORDER BY a.name ASC")
    List<Directory> findAllRoots();

    Directory findOneByName(String name, @Depth int depth);
}
```

My problem is that a directory has a list of his sub directories, and I don't want to fetch all the directories in the database when I fetch a root directory.

At the moment, if I create this data sample :

```
Directory root = new Directory("root");
Directory rootLevel1 = new Directory("rootLevel1");
Directory rootLevel2 = new Directory("rootLevel2");
root.hasChildContent(rootLevel1);
rootLevel1.hasChildContent(rootLevel2);
directoryRepository.save(root);
```

And select the root nodes :

```
directoryRepository.findAllRoots();
```

I get the root dir, having the rootLevel1 as subDir whom has the rootLevel2 as subDir.

I want to fetch just root having rootLevel1 having null (as subDir). So I don't fetch the whole directories of the DB.

I tried the @Depth param, but the call :

```
directoryRepository.findOneByName("root", 0);
```

fetches the root dir, having the rootLevel1 as subDir whom has the rootLevel2 as subDir. As if the depth was not taken into account.

How could I select a node with just his subDirectories, but not the subDirectories of subDirectories of subDirectories of ... ?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

I found that removing the Transactional annotation on my integration test affects the fecthing system of SDN.

With Transactional annotation, SDN fetches eagerly all subDirectories and loads the whole directory structure from Neo4J.

Without Transactional annotation, SDN fetched lazyly and my Directory bean has null as "subDirectories" attribute.

This solves my problem, but doesn't answer the question behind : How to set the custom depth to fetch.

Comment: Seems like it's a bug in SDN / OGM. May be related to https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/324.
Could you submit an issue please ?

Comment: @nmervaillie As a matter of fact, I have a strange "bug". I had since the beginning a Transactional annotation on the test class. But if I remove it, Iall Directory beans don't have any subDirectories. So with Transactional SDN fecthes all relationships recursively, without Transactional SDN is lazy and no relationships are fetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you share the same underlying session for you write and your read.

When you read the entities, SDN/OGM detects they are already in the session (based on the id). It returns them as they are in the session, fully populated.

When you remove the `@Transactional`, each db access executes in a new fresh session, giving the expected result.

If you need for any reason to read just after write, you might want to inject an OGM session to call a `session.clear()` to force a session refresh.

Comment: You are right, it works with Transactional annotation and a session.clear() juste after the init code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You might consider

```
MATCH p=(n:Directory)-[]-m where length(p)=1 return m limit 25
```

or

```
match p=(n)-[]-(m) with m, reduce(status ='', q IN nodes(p)| status + 'x') AS c where length(c)=1 return m, c
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't do what I want. I think the problem is in the "fetch" done by SDN4, as I want the root directories, but not their children. So I want an empty subDirectories attribute after the request has been fetched.